# Form Authentication in mvc4 using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am doing my web project in mvc4 using c#. Now i am creating a login page. The folowing code i have used.User id and password is in sql database table

#### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mem_Email)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mem_Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mem_Email)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mem_PWD)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mem_PWD)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mem_PWD)

    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
}
```

#### Controller

```
public ViewResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public RedirectResult Login(FormCollection form)
{
    string uid = Request.Form["Log_email"];
    string pwd = Request.Form["Log_pwd"];
    bool IsUser=new Member().GetLogin(uid,pwd);
    if (IsUser == true)
    {
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(uid, true);
        return Redirect("~/Member/MemberHome");
    }
    else 
        return Redirect("~/Member/Login");
}
```

#### model

```
 public bool GetLogin(string email,string pwd)
 {
     bool IsUser = false;
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString))
     {
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
             "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Mem_Register WHERE Mem_Email='" + 
             email + "' AND Mem_PWD='" + pwd + "'", con))
         {
             con.Open();
             int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
             if (count == 1)
             {   IsUser = true;   }
         }
     }
     return IsUser;      
 }
```

This is not working .the  content in the form are not passed to controller. i dont know is this the right way to login a user. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>

            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Email)

           @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)

            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)

            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)


        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: i am using this. but got in controller uid and password are null

Comment: i got it but one more doubt i have . i want redirect memberhome action alfter login. till the login how can i block the access of that page

Comment: Your ValidationMessage is using the wrong name, it's also using the completely wrong property names, since they don't match his model.

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't be using a FormCollection.  Since you are using a strongly typed model, you should be posting that model to your action.

Second, you are using the names `Mem_Email` and `Mem_PWD` in your view, but you are looking for FormCollection values of `Log_email` and `Log_pwd`, which you wouldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

the solution given by @Erik is right you are using different naming convention in the controller. you must use the same Form value that of in a view

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectResult Login(FormCollection form)
{
string uid = Request.Form["Mem_Email"];
string pwd = Request.Form["Mem_Email"];
bool IsUser=new Member().GetLogin(uid,pwd);
if (IsUser == true)
{
    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(uid, true);
    return Redirect("~/Member/MemberHome");
}
else 
    return Redirect("~/Member/Login");
}
```

with the earlier one you used ie `Log_email` and `Log_pwd` you will get null values in the controller.